# Socket.io information is not loading without refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, server, socket.io, client

React project using Socket.io, encountering an issue in the communication between server and client. When I navigate to the messages page, it should immediately send the userInfo to the backend and then expect the backend to send me the message rooms of the user with the provided info. However, this should happen as soon as the page opens, but with the current code, I cannot render the socket-received information without refreshing the page.I am getting the userInfo from the UserContext component using useContext.

My code is as follows:

**Client**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("User info =>", userInfo);
    socket.emit("get_specific_user", userInfo);
  }, []);

  socket.on("receive_specific_user_message_rooms", (data) => {
    setfilteredRooms(data.messages);
    setmessageRooms(data.messages);
  });
```

**Server**

```
  socket.on("get_specific_user", (data) => {
      console.log("specific user received =>", data.username);
      User.findById(data._id)
        .populate({
          path: "messages",
          populate: {
            path: "members",
            model: "User",
          },
        })
        .populate({
          path: "messages",
          populate: {
            path: "chat",
            model: "Chat",
          },
        })
        .then((user) => {
          socket.emit("receive_specific_user_message_rooms", user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error =>", error);
        });
    });
```